# How do "the masses" address clerics/paladins & other members of the clergy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, religions-and-deities, greyhawk

In 3.5 (Greyhawk) How do people in general refer to/address members of the various clergy?

Granted, inside the church hierarchy the clergy have their official ranks & titles they can use to address eachother (which vary according to their deities). But what about their congregations & even followers of other deities (assuming their not opposed to eachother & would otherwise extend a proper courtesy)

So, what, if any names/titles do they go by? Ie, father, brother, pastor etc or are "the people expected to know/use their official church titles/rank?..that seems a bit much to me.

I'm going for a general term of address for any faith..similar to if you see a Catholic priest in line at KFC, you might say "Morning Father" (even if your not Catholic, it's pretty obvious who they are & we all know that's a title they use regardless of our faith). If you happen to see a clergy member at a town hall mtg who looks like clergy but doesn't have the Catholic "look" you might call him pastor or brother or some other term). Ofcourse these are Christian titles, we could just as easily say, Imam or Rabbi as the situation dictates.

Please state the source of you have one.

Comment: I feel that this question would have a much better chance at having a straight, useful answer if a particular setting was used, since it’s likely to vary with those. That said, I believe some editions of D&D **did** define titles for members of certain classes at certain levels, which means there may have been description of how common folk would (or would not) use those titles, so the question may be answerable as-is.

Comment: @KRyan Yeah, but it depends on edition, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: I've specified 3.5, I originally left it open figuring they'd be near identical l, especially if a particular edition didn't specify

Comment: what campaign setting? What resources? What clergy?

Comment: In 3.5, there's no setting-agnostic answer. Unless you specify a setting (and possibly a specific faith) this is either Too Broad or Primarily Opinion-based.

Comment: Updated text I hope will help clarify.

Comment: Sorry man, still not answerable because there's not one answer.  It varies by faith.  If you call a Presbyterian pastor "Father" he's not going to take it well. Similarly in the fantasy world of Greyhawk there's not a single answer.

Comment: if there's not a single term/title to address clergy/clerics etc in general then that is the answer I needed. Thx

Comment: Voting to reopen since I believe saying "there isn't one really" is a valuable practical answer in its own right in this situation, rather than a reason for this to be closed. The question's reasonably scoped, it's a good opportunity for some Greyhawk enlightenment, just so happens the answer isn't conveniently simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There isn't a one-size-fits-all answer.

A very good starting point without doing tons of research into Gazetteers, Dragon Magazine, and other such publications, would be page 5 of Complete Champion: The D&D Churches.

But even this is very limited, since Greyhawk, specifically, (not Greyhawk: Core) has WAY MORE deities than those in the Player's Handbook.

Another source to start from would be the [Greyhawk Wiki](http://www.canonfire.com/wiki/index.php?title=Greyhawk). Prepare to do a lot of reading...

---

**Complete Champion:**

**Titles, Benefits, and Duties**

> Unless otherwise noted, the benefits for each rank gained within a church are extraordinary abilities where a designation is appropriate. For more about typical benefits, see PH2 185.